# Compiling code for Win32 applications - Windows XP and Windows Server 2003 R2

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, windows-xp

I'm on a Windows 10 computer trying to compile some C++ code with Visual Studio 2013, but I cannot get the code to run on a Windows 2003 R2 Server, and I'm unsure why.

I tried compiling with the XP flag, and I have OpenSSL and VCRedist x86 2005 - 2019 installed on the server.

My project is located at https://github.com/erfg12/EQClassic The world.exe and zone.exe work on Win2k3 server just fine, but it's the login.exe that says, "This is not a valid win32 application". To compile the code simply grab the Dependencies from https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4YtK9YXaHvQbU93Z25kY2J4WWM/view?usp=sharing and place them into the Dependencies folder and press compile in Visual Studio.

If anyone could get Login.exe to work on a Windows 2003 server or a Windows XP desktop computer that's exactly what I need. Thank you.

Comment: *This is not a valid win32 application* -- You should have investigated this error further.  This usually happens if your compiler built a corrupted executable, or you're attempting to run a 64-bit executable on a 32-bit OS.

Comment: you need to target x86 and use the XP compatible toolchain

Comment: Yes, to ensure 32-bit, you need to target x86, which would explain the "this is not a valid Win32 application" error.  If you did do that, but didn't target Windows XP, your program will start but will soon die on some message box stating that some Windows API function doesn't exist.

Comment: Another linker setting you should ensure is the "subsystem's minimum required version", which should be "5.01" for Windows XP or "5.02" for Windows Server 2003. The compiler option for this would be e.g. `/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE",5.01"` or `/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS",5.02"`.